# How to make Inheritance in DB2 Z/OS?

Tags: jakarta-ee, inheritance, db2, mainframe, zos

I'm working on a JavaEE project, with DB2 Database and JPA.
Can we make Inheritance between tables ?
In the IBM DB2 Website, i found nothing on the DB2 documentation to do this via SQL code.

This is what i want to do
Exemple :

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACTION (
TranNo int);

CREATE TABLE MOBILETRANSACTION (
Number1 varchar(255),
Number2 varchar(255) );
```

What is the word to add to the MOBILETRANSACTION Table to inherit the TRANSACTION table ?

Thank you !

Comment: Alternatively, just add an FK from `MOBILETRANSACTION` to `TRANSACTION` and do a `JOIN` in your query when retrieving data, or use a `VIEW` to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is called typed-tables in DB2. For global information about inheritance: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/c0006588.html

You first need to create a structure (type), and then you can use that structure in a table.

Please, check this first (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/c0006441.html) read all sections and them proceed with your own implementation.

Comment: Thank you ! But this is for Linux Unix and Windows, is this the same on IBM Z/os ?

Comment: I do not know. You did not specify that. I am a LUW dba

Comment: Yes i admet ! I'm changing the title to Z/os DB2 :) Thanks

Comment: For any readers on DB2 for i, we do not have this feature on IBM i. (At least not yet, as of our latest version, v7.1 TR7)